# Shorthand Regex expression to match an alphanumeric pattern instead of [A-Za-z0-9]

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate a string of the pattern `IN-XXXXXXXX-X`, where `X` is an alphumeric value. For It I need to write the regex expression

The regex I write is

```
/^IN-\w{8}-\w/g
```

But it validates alphanumeric as well as underscores in place of X.The other way would be

```
 /^IN-[A-Za-z0-9]{8}-[A-Za-z0-9]/g
```

However this seems way to long. Is there a shorthand to write `[A-Za-z0-9]` in order to validate `alphanumeric` values.

Comment: Which flavour are you using?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't... unless you're using a specific flavor of regex, such as sed, and then you can use `[:alnum:]` for example

Comment: Why do you want a shorter way of doing it in the first place?

Comment: @Sweeper My patten can include IN-X-XX-X-XXXX-XX and so on, so writing the same thing muliple times can make the regex look really longer and hence that made me think if there is a shorthand to write it

Comment: You could do `^IN-[[:alnum:]]{8}-[[:alnum:]]` or `^IN-(?i)[a-z0-9]{8}-[a-z0-9]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using `[^\W_]` to match alphanumeric characters?

`\W` - non-word characters. Basically, we match anything except non-word characters and underscores, which is the set of alphanumeric characters.

The regex would shorten to

```
^IN-[^\W_]{8}-[^\W_]
```

Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/l3rqsq/1

Comment: Yes that does work and it was what I was looking for.